# GMM panel data in R pdynmc. What's the correct format of missing values?

Tags: r

I have an unbalanced panel with firm level data. Each observation represents a one year of several variables of financial data for one firm. However, while one firm may have an observation for a given year, it may not have data for all variables relevant for estimation. My question is whether the missing values should be NA or empty in my database.

I am using a GMM Arellano-Bond 1991 method.

As you can see below I am using the `pdynmc` package.

````
m1 <- pdynmc(
  dat = final_df, 
  varname.i = "gvkey", varname.t = "fyear",
  use.mc.diff = TRUE, use.mc.lev = FALSE, use.mc.nonlin = FALSE, include.y = TRUE, 
  varname.y = "Investmentrate", 
  lagTerms.y = 3,
  fur.con = TRUE, fur.con.diff = TRUE, fur.con.lev = FALSE,
  varname.reg.fur = c("Capacityutilization", "profitrate", "financialassetsratio", "financialprofitrate",
                      "interestburden", "totaldebt", "repurchase", "volatilityvariation"),
  lagTerms.reg.fur = c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1),
  include.dum = TRUE, dum.diff = TRUE, dum.lev = FALSE, varname.dum = c("fyear","gvkey"),
  w.mat = "iid.err", std.err = "corrected",
  estimation = "twostep", opt.meth = "none"
)```
````